# MySQL high performance difference between two similar databases

Tags: mysql, php

I'm currently upgrading from TecDoc 2015 Quarter 2 database to TecDoc 2015 Quarter 4 database.

Q2 Database:
240,838,107 rows    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci 23.2 GiB

Q4 Database:
265,508,380 rows    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci 23.8 GiB

Indexes and table structures are identical.

The main difference lies in running query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ART_ID AS AID, ART_ARTICLE_NR AS ARTICLE, SUP_BRAND AS BRAND,
        SUP_ID AS BID, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT AS TD_NAME 
FROM LINK_GA_STR 
    INNER JOIN LINK_LA_TYP ON LAT_TYP_ID = 243 AND 
    LAT_GA_ID = LGS_GA_ID 
    INNER JOIN LINK_ART ON LA_ID = LAT_LA_ID 
    INNER JOIN ARTICLES ON ART_ID = LA_ART_ID 
    INNER JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID AND 
    DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 35 
    INNER JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID 
    INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS ON SUP_ID = ART_SUP_ID 
WHERE LGS_STR_ID = 42189;
```

Q2 results: Returned 833 rows, 0.749 seconds.

Q4 results: Return 836 rows, 3.72 seconds.

As you see, there is huge difference. Same queries with different parameters on the Q4 database can take upto 15 seconds.

I've tried tweaking some setttings in my.cnf, but nothing seems to help.

EXPLAINS:

[Quarter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN6Wu.jpg)

[Quarter 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzVzO.jpg)

SERVER:
GCC: n1-standard (vCPUs: 1, RAM: 3.75 GB) with 150GB persistent disk

Comment: Could you post your plans as text using text from the MySQL client (use formatting) and post SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G for all tables?7

Comment: Did you run the queries twice?  The first time will probably be I/O-bound; the second time will be more indicative of the 'real' time.

Comment: Also provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`

Comment: From the `CREATE TABLEs` and buffer sizes, we may be able to advise on a short-term patch.  Oh, could we see `SHOW TABLE STATUS` -- want to see sizes of individual tables.  The long-term solution _may_ involve more RAM.